# How can I style my page so that a form's submit button is always at the bottom of the window?

Tags: html, css, window

I have a page that already has a footer permanently "bottom-aligned" using a container with 100% height and the following css:

```
#footer {
position: absolute;
left: 0px;
right: 0px;
bottom: 0px;
font-size: 12px;
}
```

What I would like to do is have the buttons for my page's form (denoted in the html below by the div with class "actionButtons") always directly above the footer, regardless of the other content of the form. I can guarantee that the form's content will never cause overflow.

```
<html>
<body>
    <div>
        <div class="wideContent">   
            <form>           
                <div class="actionButtons" style="text-align:right;">
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>    
    </div>

    <div id="footer"></div>   
</body>
</html>
```

I've been messing with height/min-height with no success. What css would I need for the html above to always place the "actionButtons" div at the bottom of the window, just above the footer? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Make the actionbuttons div also be absolutely positioned, and give it a `bottom: xxx` that places it above the footer?

Comment: @Marc B When I do that, my actionbuttons float at the bottom of the form, overlapping it (nowhere near the bottom of the page). The form has Position: Relative set, if that makes a difference.

Comment: It does make a diff. pos:abs climbs back up the DOM tree until it finds a node that's pos:rel (or hits the top) to do the positioning calculations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the `<form>` has `position:relative` the only way I can think of forcing the buttons to the bottom is `position:fixed`, for example…

```
#footer {
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
    font-size:12px;
    height:25px;
}

.actionButtons {
    position:fixed;
    bottom:25px;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    height:10px;
}
```

…as in [**this demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/aaFy2/). But it will require a height being set on the `#footer` which matches the `bottom` on the `.actionButtons` to place it correctly. (I have included a `height` on the `.actionButtons` for demo purposes).